# Is there a way to subscribe to aws marketplace product using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-marketplace

I wanted to subscribe to influxdb cloud in aws marketplace - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-4e7raoxoxsl4y?href=_ptnr_web_docs_gettingstarted. Is there a way to do that using terraform?

Answer (score 5):

I believe, as you need to subscribe (terms and conditions and all) - you need to do it one time via console. After that you should be able to provision the resource.

There is a request out there to get this functionality added: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17146

Comment: This was released in v4.58.0 of the AWS provider; they've since released v5.